# Rails app on apache, passenger lists the directory instead of showing login page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

I am deploying a ruby-on-rails application.

I have configured apache and passenger and the http server is listening on port 80.
When I try to access the home page using the browser, I simply get a list of files and directories instead of the home page.

Following are snippets from the apache config.

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.27/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.27
     PassengerDefaultRuby /home/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby
   </IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/ubuntuvm-4.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@ubuntuvm-4.com
    ServerName ubuntuvm-4
    ServerAlias www.ubuntuvm-4.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/www/myapp/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What is going wrong?
Could it be that I am trying to access the page via the ip address
http://192.168.0.12?
If you want me to put any other config, please shout.

Comment: Have you enabled the site? And the mod? Use a2ensite and a2enmod. Also, this is probably a better fit for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: yes i have enabled the site using  sudo a2ensite ubuntuvm-4.conf. How do I use a2enmod?

Answer (score 0):

try to copy the content of the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ubuntuvm-4.conf` 
to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ubuntuvm-4.conf`

```
cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/ubuntuvm-4.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ubuntuvm-4.conf
```

You need to create your config like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName ubuntuvm-4
        <Location /home/user1/www/myapp/public>
            PassengerBaseURI /
            PassengerAppRoot /home/user1/www/myapp
        </Location>
          DocumentRoot /home/user1/www/myapp/public
          <Directory /home/user1/www/myapp/public>
             AllowOverride all
             RailsEnv production
             # MultiViews must be turned off.
             Options -MultiViews
             # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
             Require all granted
          </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There is already a file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ubuntuvm-4.conf at that location with the same contents.

Comment: i see that you didn't define `PassengerBaseURI` and `PassengerAppRoot` , i updated my answer

Comment: I tried the new config, but there is no change. Anything else I can try?

Comment: did you updated in `sites-enabled/ubuntuvm-4.conf` and restart your apache? what apache version are you using?

Comment: I updated the file, version is :Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109136/discussion-between-abdoo-dev-and-ajay).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem trying to deploy a 4.2.1 Rails app on Ubuntu 12.04 using Ruby 2.3.2 (RVM because .deb packaged version is damn too old !!) Apache 2.2 and Passenger 5.0.4 (.deb).
Well, after wasting days to try to figure out why passenger wouldn't start (I did this a thousand times, it always worked), I realized it was only because Passenger couldn't print its logs anywhere. So, if you already tried everything you read on forums, just try to add a path to a log file in your apache configuration :

```
PassengerLogFile /var/log/passenger.log
```

and it worked like magic. Hope this helps.